# Debugging AWS RDS access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to connect to a MySQL RDS from outside of AWS (from machines in my office).

I have everything set up correctly in that I can connect to the database from some IP addresses but not from others (there is IP address white-listing and all the IP addresses are white-listed in the same way).

Is there some way that I can see in AWS what connections are being accepted and rejected? I have tried looking at VPC Flow Logs where I can see connections accepted from my IP address but I can't see rejections from the IP address I'm trying to connect from. I have checked the corporate firewall and it appears that the rejection is from AWS.

Comment: AWS firewalls RDS instances with the configured Security Group. The security group should be configured to allow access from (at least) the IP you are coming from to TCP port 3306 (for MySQL).
Since you are connecting from your office, you should also make sure that the routing is set up correctly: You will need either a VPN, or expose the RDS instances with a public IP address.

Comment: Yeah it's all set up okay in that I can access it from from one IP range in the office but it's just not working from another IP range in the office.